# AWS Fargate Task missing States ACTIVATING, DEACTIVATING, STOPPING

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I'm facing one issue, that is when fargate task running, task states not covering full lifecycle i.e. PROVISIONING **-->** PENDING **-->** ACTIVATING **-->**  RUNNING **-->** DEACTIVATING **-->** STOPPING **-->** DEPROVISIONING **-->** STOPPED

I have seen that task state covering only: PROVISIONING **-->** PENDING **-->** RUNNING **-->** DEPROVISIONING **-->** STOPPED

Where are the missing states? i.e. ACTIVATING, DEACTIVATING, STOPPING

Inside CloudWatch Log Insights:

[image]

What is the reason of this?

Suggest me how can I configure to see all the states of each task.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing these states? Somewhere in the AWS console? Through the CLI tool or something?

Comment: Inside CloudWatch Logs Insights: